# How do i stop or turn off the x-server?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, command-line

I'm trying to do this tutorial :

[Installing CUDA Under Ubuntu 10.04](http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_CUDA_Under_Ubuntu_10.04)

I need the command that would completely stop/turn off the x-server. When i try to install the NVidia developer driver, I get a blue screen telling me

> Error: cant install with x-server running, please turn it off (something like that)

`sudo service gdm stop` worked at the time I guess, (didnt give any errors) but the x-server is still running. Is this the command I should be using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will kill the server. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 which moves you to the system console.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

When installation get complete, you are returned to same command prompt/terminal type screen. Now execute this command to start X SERVER back:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start
```

This will start the X SERVER and you gets the old UBUNTU LOGIN SCREEN

Comment: what do i do when i run the first command (stop). and i get a rather than invoking init, use the service(8) utility. what do i do? can i force it to run without problems?

Comment: I just tested that command in my terminal and it killed the xserver from there too.

Comment: it only worked before going in system console. so type the command then press CTRL + ALT + F1 to install the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `service` command instead of calling /etc/init.d:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

And then to start it again:

```
sudo service gdm start
```